# How to restrict the future month in material month picker?

Tags: jquery

I added the material month picker in my code i need to restrict the future month. How to limit that. This is my code

```
<input id="materialpicker002" type="text" value="January 2017">

 var monthpicker = new MaterialDatepicker('#materialpicker002', {
  type: 'month',
  lang: 'en',
  color: "#165fab"
});
```

Comment: any suggestion for this